# How to edit Yoast Breadcrumbs JSON-LD array

Tags: php, wordpress, json-ld, yoast

I'm using Yoast plugin Wordpress.

My page url is `https://abc.example.com/company/aurora-cannabis/latest-news`

My actual URL is `https://abc.example.com/company/aurora-cannabis/` which is custom post type page.

To create custom URL, I used filter

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'company_page_rules');
```

Because of this, in the Google Structured data testing tool in Breadcrumbs section it shows URL `https://abc.example.com/company/aurora-cannabis`

But I need URL `https://abc.example.com/company/aurora-cannabis/latest-news` in the breadcrumbs.

[image]

Comment: This works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053348/wp-seo-yoast-plugin-breadcrumb-and-json-ld-breadcrumblist-integration

Comment: just need to edit little bit code. :)